# PhP File Uploading not working, fine until upload

Tags: php, file, uploading

I've been working for a while on this file uploading for php, but I can't get it to work. When I click upload the 'if' statement goes to false.

If someone could point out to me where I'm going wrong, it would be great.

```
<?php
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];


    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if(isset($name)) {
        if(!empty($name)) {

            $location = "uploads/";
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
                echo "Uploaded";
            } else {
                echo $location . $name;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $tmp_name;
            }

        } else {
            echo "Please choose a file!";
        }
    }
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: is it isset($name) or isset($file)..??

Comment: @FranciscoCarvalho Actually `empty($_FILES)`, because `$_FILES` is always set

Comment: try a `var_dump($_FILES)` to see if there are any uploads at all

Comment: @djay sorry, unfocused...

Answer (score 3):

your $locatIon is probably wrong, try passing an absolute path ( the path in your example is relative to the current working directory, and it may not be writable )

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Forgot to make the uploads folder writable.

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br>

<form action="getfile.php" method="post"><br>
Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**getfile.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Process Uploaded File</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['tmp_name'],
       "../uploads/{$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']}")

?>
</body>
</html>
```